# No injectable members. Do you want to add an injectable constructor?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I have these 2 simple modules modules:

**AppModule**

```
@Module(injects =
        {
                HomeActivity.class,
        },
        includes = {
                GoogleApiModule.class,
                DbModule.class,
                GcmModule.class,
        })
public class AppModule {

    private final Application app;

    public AppModule(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return app;
    }
}
```

**ApiModule**

```
@Module(injects =
        {                
                LoginFragment.class,
        }, addsTo = AppModule.class)
public class ApiModule {

    private final Context context;

    public ApiModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Publicapi providePublicApi() {
        Publicapi.Builder builder = new 
        return new Publicapi();
    }    
}
```

Beacause of `@Inject PublicApi` in `LoginFragment` compiler complains:

```
No injectable members on myapp.publicapi.Publicapi. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by myapp.fragments.LoginFragment for myapp.modules.AppModule
```

I've been reading several threads I was sure I'm doing it right, been obviously wrong. What is wrong in this setup?

Comment: We need a little more code on how you use the `ObjectGraph` to inject your `Publicapi` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Publicapi must have a constructor method who receive the context, and you have to assign it an context class attribute. I mean:

```
public Publicapi(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Then... in ApiModule you have to instantiate the constructor sending the context as param. Something like that:

```
// (With "a" in lower case like the class name) !!!
@Provides
@Singleton
Publicapi providesPublicapi(Context context) { 
   return new Publicapi(context);
}
```

Regards!